# Spring MVC don't retrieve roles

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, ldap

I have next configuration in a Spring webapp, but I am not able to get ROLES from the users.

**config**

```
<security:authentication-manager>
<security:ldap-authentication-provider 
    user-search-filter="(uid={0})"
    user-search-base="ou=users"
    group-search-filter="(uniqueMember={0})"
    group-search-base="ou=groups"
    group-role-attribute="cn"
    role-prefix="ROLE_">
</security:ldap-authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>

<security:ldap-server url="ldap://x.x.x.x:389/dc=test,dc=com" 
 manager-dn="cn=admin,dc=test,dc=com" 
 manager-password="test" />
```

**[Ldap Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpkoW.jpg)**

I try with other configurations but nothing, with both solutions I get UserLogged but not the authentications.

```
<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider
        ref='ldapAuthProvider' />
</security:authentication-manager>
<bean id="contextSource"
    class="org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource">
    <constructor-arg value="ldap://x.x.x.x:389/dc=test,dc=com" />
    <property name="userDn" value="cn=admin,dc=test,dc=com" />
    <property name="password" value="test" />
</bean>

<bean id="ldapAuthProvider"
    class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator">
            <constructor-arg ref="contextSource" />
            <property name="userDnPatterns">
                <list>
                    <value>uid={0},ou=users</value>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator">
            <constructor-arg ref="contextSource" />
            <constructor-arg value="ou=groups" />
            <property name="groupRoleAttribute" value="cn" />
            <!-- the following properties are shown with their default values -->
            <property name="searchSubtree" value="false" />
            <property name="rolePrefix" value="ROLE_" />
            <property name="convertToUpperCase" value="true" />
        </bean>

    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Can anyone help ?